# How to make the ARTIFACT_NAME Dynamic?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, dockerfile

While trying to create docker build, getting error as below:

```
Status: Downloaded newer image for adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:alpine-jre
 ---> fcb7960593e0
Step 13/18 : ENV ARTIFACT_NAME=userservice.jar
 ---> Running in f9cb2c5751ce
Removing intermediate container f9cb2c5751ce
 ---> a8d457c0023a
Step 14/18 : ENV APP_HOME=/usr/app/
 ---> Running in 4376cb0c3120
Removing intermediate container 4376cb0c3120
 ---> 6df0ab62c566
Step 15/18 : WORKDIR $APP_HOME
 ---> Running in e44347ce7a6b
Removing intermediate container e44347ce7a6b
 ---> ac63acfe40e6
Step 16/18 : COPY --from=TEMP_BUILD_IMAGE $APP_HOME/build/libs/*.jar ${ARTIFACT_NAME}
COPY failed: no source files were specified
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

**Here is the docker file:**

```
# using multistage docker build
# ref: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/
    
# temp container to build using gradle
FROM gradle:6.9.1-jdk11 AS TEMP_BUILD_IMAGE
ENV APP_HOME=/usr/app/
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY build.gradle settings.gradle $APP_HOME
  
COPY gradle $APP_HOME/gradle
COPY --chown=gradle:gradle . /home/gradle/src
USER root
RUN chown -R gradle /home/gradle/src
    
RUN gradle build || return 0
COPY . .
RUN gradle clean build
    
# actual container
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:alpine-jre
ENV ARTIFACT_NAME=userservice.jar <--- Here (fails)
ENV APP_HOME=/usr/app/
    
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY --from=TEMP_BUILD_IMAGE $APP_HOME/build/libs/*.jar ${ARTIFACT_NAME} <--- Here (fails)
    
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Dspring.profiles.active=h2_db", "-jar", "${ARTIFACT_NAME}"]
```

If we hardcode build file name as below, then things works fine:

```
# actual container
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:alpine-jre
ENV ARTIFACT_NAME=userservice-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar <--- Here (works)
ENV APP_HOME=/usr/app/
    
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY --from=TEMP_BUILD_IMAGE $APP_HOME/build/libs/$ARTIFACT_NAME .  <--- Here (works)
```

**How to copy the latest build artifacts as a specific name? In above case userservice-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar should be picked as userservice.jar.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define `ENV APP_HOME=/usr/app/`, the final `COPY source` becomes `/usr/app//build/libs/*.jar`.

It looks for wildcard, docker build can't handle it well. But if you don't use wildcard, above `//` works well.

So, for your scenario, just change to `ENV APP_HOME=/usr/app` could fix your problem.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM gradle:6.9.1-jdk11 AS TEMP_BUILD_IMAGE
ENV APP_HOME=/usr/app/
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
RUN mkdir -p build/libs; cd build/libs; touch userservice-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar

FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:alpine-jre
ENV ARTIFACT_NAME=userservice.jar
#ENV APP_HOME=/usr/app/
ENV APP_HOME=/usr/app

WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY --from=TEMP_BUILD_IMAGE $APP_HOME/build/libs/*.jar ${ARTIFACT_NAME}

EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Dspring.profiles.active=h2_db", "-jar", "${ARTIFACT_NAME}"]
```

**Execution:**

```
# docker build . --no-cache
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
......
Step 9/11 : COPY --from=TEMP_BUILD_IMAGE $APP_HOME/build/libs/*.jar ${ARTIFACT_NAME}
 ---> d9a7219be751
Step 10/11 : EXPOSE 8080
 ---> Running in df81e955b4b9
Removing intermediate container df81e955b4b9
 ---> c3f019d65533
Step 11/11 : ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Dspring.profiles.active=h2_db", "-jar", "${ARTIFACT_NAME}"]
 ---> Running in 7c62bf624cb1
Removing intermediate container 7c62bf624cb1
 ---> e5377e14375d
Successfully built e5377e14375d
```

**Additional**, if you change backend to `BUILDKIT` like next, the `/usr/app/` still can work, so I guess this related to docker implemenation issue:

**Execution with buildkit:**

```
# DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --progress=plain . --no-cache
......
#10 [stage-1 3/3] COPY --from=TEMP_BUILD_IMAGE /usr/app//build/libs/*.jar us...
#10 DONE 0.1s

#11 exporting to image
#11 exporting layers 0.0s done
#11 writing image sha256:730755ba444c13f289614b64d5cfd3be900b94c8d668307477ed2908183df14f
#11 writing image sha256:730755ba444c13f289614b64d5cfd3be900b94c8d668307477ed2908183df14f done
#11 DONE 0.0s
```